# remove checkmark from menuitem c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menuitem with ischeckable and it comes with a checkmark. i wish to remove the checkmark that comes with it. I have a packicon but it doesnt overwrite the checkmark also. Any help please!

```
<MenuItem Header="Save Trace" Command="{Binding SaveXML}" 
                              IsCheckable="True" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding SavingTrace,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              IsEnabled="{Binding StartTraceEnable}" >
                              <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Restore" />
                              </MenuItem>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove checkmark from MenuItems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680392/remove-checkmark-from-menuitems)

Comment: i had checked it out, but i have no idea how to collapse the value during runtime. so it didnt help me.

Comment: *"no idea how to collapse the value during runtime"* - change menu item `Visibility` property.

Comment: since i have used isenabled property for the menuitem, its disbaled during runtime.

Comment: `Visibility` and `IsEnabled` are two different things. `Visibility = Collapsed` should truly hide menu item from the screen.

Comment: okay. let me try doing that. thanks!